# Flutter: How to use GoRouter with Bloc to route from Splash Screen to Login Screen

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, bloc, flutter-go-router

So I switched to Go router recently in my app since it is very easy to implement. But I am having trouble moving from Splash Screen to Login Screen. I have logic in my Splash Screen where I check if the user is logged in or not. Based on the user's auth, the screen either goes to Login Screen or the Home page.

This is Splash Screen.

```
    class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = "/SplashScreen";

  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('Listener: $state');
        }
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
          if (state.authStatus == AuthStatus.unAuthenticated) {
            GoRouter.of(context).go('/login');

            Navigator.pushNamed(context, SignUpScreen.routeName);
          } else if (state.authStatus == AuthStatus.authenticated) {
            //Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst);
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomePage.routeName);
          }
        });
      },
      builder: (context, Object? state) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print('object: $state');
        }
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  "Welcome to Musajjal",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/musajjalBlue.png',
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Hifz ul Quran Records",
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                const CircularProgressIndicator(
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Next, this. is my Go Router function

```
GoRouter _router(AuthenticationBloc bloc) {
return GoRouter(
  routes: <GoRoute>[
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
      routes: <GoRoute>[
        GoRoute(path: 'login', builder: (context, state) => LoginScreen()),
        GoRoute(
            path: 'signUp', builder: (context, state) => SignUpScreen()),
        GoRoute(path: 'homePage', builder: (context, state) => HomePage())
      ],
      redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        final isLoggedIn =
            bloc.state.authStatus == AuthStatus.authenticated;
        final isLoggingIn = state.location == '/login';
        print(isLoggedIn);

        if (!isLoggedIn && !isLoggingIn) return '/login';
        if (isLoggedIn && isLoggingIn) return '/homePage';
        return null;
      },
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

The issue is the app gets stuck on Splash Screen and it does not move forward to login screen. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Try the follwing code:

#### `main.dart`

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<AuthenticationBloc>(
            create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc),  Specify the BlocProvider here
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
            theme: customTheme(context),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            routerConfig: router,
  }
```

#### `router.dart`

```
final GoRouter router = GoRouter(routes: [
  GoRoute(
      path: "/",
      builder: (context, state) {
        return BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
          buildWhen: (oldState, newState) {
            return oldState is AuthInitialState;
           },
          builder: (context, state) {
             if (state is AuthLoading) {
              // return const SplashScreen();           // alternative way
               context.goNamed(SplashScreen.routeName);  Display your splash screen here and you can provide delay while changing state in your bloc
            }
            else if (state is AuthenticationUnauthenticated) {
               context.goNamed(LoginPage.routeName);  
            } else if (state is Authenticated) {
                context.goNamed(HomePage.routeName);           
             } else {
              return const Scaffold();
            }
          },
        );
      }),
```

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Redirection-topic.html) says to use the `redirect` parameter to add a redirection mechanic to your application.

There are two ways to implement redirections with go_router:

- At a top-level (top-level redirection), which means that any time your app will make a navigation, the `redirect` function will be called to see whether your app will navigate to the page it has been asked for, or redirect to something else of your choice (you choose the logic you want); this redirection is defined on the `GoRouter` constructor
- A a route-level (route-level redirection), which is defined on the `GoRoute` constructor, so only on a specific route navigation, and not any navigation event like it is done at the top-level redirection

For your case, navigating from a Splash screen to a Login screen or a Home Screen, you could imagine to use the top-level redirection way where you retrieve the Authentication state of your app and

- if your user is authenticated, you redirect to the Home Page (which means returning null in the `redirect` parameter as mentioned in the documentation)
- if your user is unauthenticated, you redirect to the Login Page for the user to log in
- if you don't know yet if the user is authenticated or not because you are still fetching this information, you display the Splash page (you could imagine having an AuthenticationStatus enumeration with three values: authenticated, unauthenticated and unknown, like it is done in the Login implementation example made for the Bloc package ([link here](https://bloclibrary.dev//#/flutterlogintutorial?id=authentication-repository))

An issue I'm finding here is that the `redirect` function is called when an navigation event is triggered, but what we would generally want is the transition to be made automatically from the Splash Page to the Login Page or Home Page depending on the authentication status of the user.
You can see the [Bloc package tutorial](https://bloclibrary.dev//#/flutterlogintutorial?id=authentication-repository) I've mentioned before, it gives many hints to achieve this. I am currently trying to do the same thing using GoRouter.

**Edit (sept 12th 2023):**

- I came up with the following solution

  ```
  class MyFirstPage extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyFirstPage({super.key});

    static String routePath = '/';

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return BlocListener<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          switch (state.status) {
            case AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated:
              context.go('/login');
              break;
            case AuthenticationStatus.authenticated:
              context.go('/home');
              break;
            case AuthenticationStatus.unknown:
              break;
          }
        },
        child: const SplashPage(),
      );
    }
  }
  ```

With the following GoRouter config:

```
final router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
    initialLocation: MyFirstPage.routePath,
    redirect: (context, state) {
      var authStatus = context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().state.status;

      if (authStatus == AuthenticationStatus.unknown) {
        return MyFirstPage.routePath;
      } else if (authStatus == AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated) {
        return LoginPage.routePath;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        path: MyFirstPage.routePath,
        builder: (_, __) => const MyFirstPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: SplashPage.routeName,
        path: SplashPage.routePath,
        builder: (_, __) => const SplashPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: LoginPage.routeName,
        path: LoginPage.routePath,
        builder: (_, __) => LoginPage(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: HomePage.routeName,
        path: HomePage.routePath,
        builder: (_, __) => const HomePage(),
      ),
    ],
    });
```

Explanation:

- The starting page of the app is `MyFirstPage` which displays my SplashPage while fetching for the authentication status of the user.
- If the user is not authenticated (`AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated`), we redirect the user to the LoginPage (`context.go('/login')`)
- If the user is authenticated (`AuthenticationStatus.authenticated`), we redirect the user to the HomePage (`context.go('/home')`)
- If we cannot retrieve the auth status (`AuthenticationStatus.unknown`), we do nothing since we're already on the SplashPage, and we wait until we get the AuthStatus (here, until the AuthenticationBloc's state is updated)
- In the `redirect` parameter of the `GoRouter` constructor, what we do is to check if the user is still authenticated anytime we have an navigation event. We do that by checking their authentication status: if it changed to `AuthenticationStatus.unauthenticated`, we redirect the user to the Login Page, if it changed to `Authentication.unknown`, we redirect the user to MyFirstPage which displays the SplashScreen and waits for an update of the user's authentication status (I haven't extensively tried it to guarantee it)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the logic in the redirect to

```
if (!isLoggedIn && !isLoggingIn) return '/login';
if (isLoggedIn) return '/homePage';
```

also, consider having the login logic as OR instead of AND --optional

```
if (!isLoggedIn || !isLoggingIn) return '/login';
```